# UI Container in thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

brothers in code.

I'm trying to make my WinForms app multi threaded. In DoWork of my background worker I've got a method which changes few controls using MethodInvoker delegate. My question is if I have to invoke every control every time I want to change it from another thread or maybe there is some kind of container of controls which I can invoke to avoid multiple invoking certain controls?

Comment: You could simply `Invoke` a method on the UI-thread that does all the updates of the controls you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking means scheduling your code to run on the thread that owns the controls, which in all straightforward cases would be the very same thread for *all* of your controls. So while you do have to invoke every time you want to interact with a control, you can in practice "pool" as many interactions as you wish together and only invoke once for the whole piece (doing so will be more performant).

If you want to "hide" the invocations you 'd have to write a class that, when triggered, would detect changes to its properties and use `Invoke` on code that interacts with your controls in a manner dependent on these properties. So the workflow would be:

1. Your worker modifies the "controller"'s properties, without invoking. This does not have any immediate effect.
2. At some point, the controller is "triggered" (perhaps periodically by the worker?).
3. The controller detects (or already knows) what changes were made to its properties and how these translate to invoking code on controls. It invokes a block of code that interact with the controls accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if I have to invoke every control every time I want to change it from another 
>   thread or maybe there is some kind of container of controls which I can invoke to avoid multiple 
>   invoking certain controls?

You have to invoke every time yiou want to change the UI. The invoke operation can do more than changing one peroeprty -it can be a complete function udpating 100 controls.

Minimizing invokes is good for performance.

No, there is no predefined container. You are assumed to be an able program an invoke, for example for an anonymous code block, yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Technically all of your GUI is created on the main thread, so If you invoke say a main panel on the GUI then within that invocation method you can alter other controls on the GUI all within that method

Plus if your background worker was created on main thread then you can call report progress event back on main thread... Which means invocation not required.  Main purpose of background workers really.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to change the text on two `Label`s. Assuming they belong to the same `Form`, you can do this either by individual calls to `Invoke`...

```
void buttonInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Invoke((Action)(() => label1.Text = "A1"));
    Invoke((Action)(() => label2.Text = "A2"));
}
```

...or by grouping then in a single `Invoke`, to save some typing and increase performance.

```
private void buttonInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Invoke(
        (Action)(() => {
            label1.Text = "B1";
            label2.Text = "B2";
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void UpdateControl<T>(T control, Action<T> action) where T : Control
{
  if(control.InvokeRequired) 
    control.Invoke(() => action(control));
  else
    action(control);
}
```